# Unrecognized scheme in server address

Tags: asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I just tried to debug a project which is built with asp.net core 2.0. It however compiles successfully but failed when it starts the kestrel server.

The runtime exception I get is

> Unrecognized scheme in server address ' http://localhost:56950/'. Only
>   'http://' is supported.

As far as I understood it, it has to do something with `https://` server schemes. But I don't remember If I accidentally put `https` configuration somewhere.

I stumbled upon [this](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/1851) source with no luck so far.

Can anyone put me in right direction ?

**Error**

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like an issue with a leading 'space' - url should not begin with space.

Check why your address is starting from a 'wite' character - probably that's spell mistake in your config (see Project Properties -> web tab).